# Memory usage concerns on Rails ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

To encrypt and store user information in database, my Rails application uses `salt` (per User) to generate `key` using `ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator`. However, the default iterations performed by `generate_key` method is `2**16` [1]. Performing key generation using the user's `salt` on every read (for decryption) and write (for encryption) is slowing down my application.

I found that `ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator` can be used to cache the key if `salt` and `length` used for key generation are remains same [2]. Internally, it uses `Concurrent::Map` [3] for caching the keys. Using `ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator` has increased performance of my application because it doesn't generate the key always.

**Will this increase memory usage of my application to a level where it can bring the app down?**

*References:*

1. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activesupport/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb#L16
2. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CachingKeyGenerator.html
3. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activesupport/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb#L33

Comment: Really ? How many users du you have ? Keys don't really take up that much space ..

Comment: We have around a million users.

Comment: It depends. I'd suggest using memory profiling on the near-real volume of data instead of relying on forum opinions :) Probably, it also makes sense to not cache everything - chances are users' activity profiles are very different, and there are (roughly speaking) 20% users who cause 80% pressure on your infrastructure. Caching just their keys will reduce performance problems with reasonable memory trade-offs...

Answer (score 0):

**Sharing a "working" solution**

Since `ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator` uses `Concurrent::Map`, I found that caching keys will result in increased memory usage proportional to the number of users (provided all the requests are somehow routed to same node).

For solving this, I wrote a similar `CachingKeyGenerator` that wraps `ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator` and `ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore`.

```rb
class CachingKeyGenerator
  BASE = Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
  LENGTH = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.key_len
  KEY_EXPIRY = 1.day

  def initialize
    @key_generator = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
    @keys_cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new(expires_in: KEY_EXPIRY)
  end

  def generate_key(salt)
    key = @keys_cache.fetch(salt)
    if key.nil?
      key = @key_generator.generate_key(salt, LENGTH)
      @keys_cache.write(salt, key)
    end
    key
  end
end
```

As per the Rails documentation, `ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore` is thread-safe and implements an LRU based cleanup mechanism [1]. This should make the cache's memory usage deterministic - to a size bound set for the memory store (default - 32Mb, can be defined during initialization).

*P.S: Yet to deploy this on production, will update here if I face any unexpected issues.*

[1] http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html